# Theorem 7.3.17 in (Qingliu) Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, divisors-algebraic-geometry

[image]

I don't understand the logic [As $F$ is a finite scheme, $\mathcal{O}_X(E)|_F\cong \mathcal{O}_F$].
Let $i:F\to X$ be the closed immersion, then the isomorphism really is $\mathcal{O}_X(E)\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X}i_* \mathcal{O}_F\cong i_* \mathcal{O}_F$. I can see that this is true if $E\cap F=\emptyset$. But lemma 3.6 that was used to construct $E$ and $F$ didn't demand that they have no intersection.
[image]

Comment: I think you can do this by writing $E = (E+A) - A$ for some sufficiently ample divisor $A$. Then you can perturb $E+A$ and $A$ away from the support of $F$, reducing to the case $E \cap F = \emptyset$.

Comment: @TabesBridges so you also think the case $E\cap F \neq \emptyset$ is wrong here?

Comment: No, it just requires further argument as I indicated before.

Comment: @TabesBridges I mean in the non-empty intersection case, is the isomorphism still true? I know the theorem is still true.

Comment: Yes, the isomorphism is still true; the intuition is that a vector bundle on a (reduced) point is just a vector space, so cannot be twisted in any way. My first comment contains the argument for reducing the case $E\cap F \neq \emptyset$ to the case $E\cap F = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By lemma 7.1.29, we have $\mathcal{O}_X(E)|_F\cong \mathcal{O}_F(E|_F)$. Since $F$ is a finite scheme, every Cartier divisor over $F$ is principal (jsut unwrap the definitions of Cartier divisor) so $\mathcal{O}_F(E|_F)\cong\mathcal{O}_F$.